# Navbar works but clicked element not highlighted

Tags: angularjs, navbar, yeoman

I generated an AngularJS app with yeoman. The navbar works and when I click on the an element the enw page loads, however the clicked button don't get highlighted.

[image]

This is the navbar code

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!/">myApp</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#!/">1</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#!/page2">2</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#!/page3">3</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#!/page4">4</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#!/page5">5</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#!/page6">6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. Here there is one of them

Create a **controller** and set a var called `currentLink` like this

```
//...
.controller('headerCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.currentLink = 1;

    $scope.set = function(link){
           $scope.currentLink = link;
    }
});
//...
```

now in your html modify your code like this:

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="headerCtrl">
<!--...-->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ng-class="{'active': currentLink == 1}"><a href="#!/" ng-click="headerCtrl.set(1);">1</a></li>
          <li ng-class="{'active': currentLink == 2}"><a ng-href="#!/page2" ng-click="headerCtrl.set(2);">2</a></li>
          <li ng-class="{'active': currentLink == 3}" ><a ng-href="#!/page3" ng-click="headerCtrl.set(3);">3</a></li>
          <li ng-class="{'active': currentLink == 4}"><a ng-href="#!/page4" ng-click="headerCtrl.set(4);">4</a></li>
          <!-- and so on-->
        </ul>
<!--...-->
</div>
```

This way with `ng-class` you switch from active or not every link and with `ng-click` you set that link as active when clicked;